# Power tool for scraping paint off windows

Tags: paint

I need to scrape paint off of a bunch of windows where the painters painted over the glass. I know I can use a razor, but that takes a long time.

Are there any power tools that I could use to make the process faster?

Comment: How much of the glass is painted?  Is it just like a  1/8th of an inch or slopped on?

Comment: Power tools on glass?  Let us know how THAT works out !

Comment: Get one of those old time vibrators that straps to your hand and hold the razor tool and let the vibrations do the work.

Answer (score 3):

### No no no, you really don't want to do that

As Alaska Man says... "power tools near glass, what could go wrong?"

I strip *a lot* of paint off *a lot* of windows because I hate masking.  And it's not super-easy latex paint either - it's alkyds or LPUs (which are a fight) or worse, 2-pack epoxy primer, which has an uncanny bite on glass (how??)    Or silicone sealants.

Just go to town with a bottle of Windex and a stack of sharp razor blades.  It's really fast work, and I don't see how a power tool could help. Keep the area wet with Windex.  If you don't want to waste Windex that way, dilute any lliquid soap; the purpose is to lubricate the razor blade to keep it from scratching and extend its life.  Let a good rain take the soap away and windex it at the end.  **Do Not Do This Dry**.

If it's slow going, you're doing it dry, or using dull razor blades (change those *lickity split*, they are your enemy as they will scratch the glass!  Also, there are no medals/awards for conserving razor blades, and they recycle 100% because the landfill shreds your trash and runs a magnet over it to pick up ferrous waste).